# Unmet dependencies using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies, debian

I spawned a gcp linux instance using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Jammy.

I keep getting error messages when I try to install packages using apt.

For example,
`apt install wget` outputs:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdart6-collision-bullet-dev : Depends: libdart6-collision-bullet (= 6.12.2-2043~202208070503~ubuntu22.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libdart6-collision-ode-dev : Depends: libdart6-collision-ode (= 6.12.2-2043~202208070503~ubuntu22.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libdart6-external-imgui-dev : Depends: libdart6-external-imgui (= 6.12.2-2043~202208070503~ubuntu22.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libdart6-gui : Depends: libdart6-utils but it is not going to be installed
 libdart6-gui-osg-dev : Depends: libdart6-gui-osg (= 6.12.2-2043~202208070503~ubuntu22.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libdart6-optimizer-nlopt-dev : Depends: libdart6-optimizer-nlopt (= 6.12.2-2043~202208070503~ubuntu22.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libdart6-utils-dev : Depends: libdart6-utils (= 6.12.2-2043~202208070503~ubuntu22.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libdart6-utils-urdf-dev : Depends: libdart6-utils-urdf (= 6.12.2-2043~202208070503~ubuntu22.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

I have tried these following commands, yet still getting errors:

```
sudo apt-get install -f  
sudo dpkg –configure -a 
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Comment: The package `libdart6-collision-bullet-dev` is **not** a Ubuntu package; so I'd check your sources, or where you're getting `wget` as your question is incorrect or missing details for a clean Ubuntu 22.04 LTS install   (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libdart6-collision-bullet-dev)

Comment: Edir your question with the full output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. These commands should complete without errors before attempting to install new software.  The error also tells you to run `apt --fix-broken install` but you don't mention that you tried it. Why not? Please add the complete outputs of these commands.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problems:

```
root@deploy:~# apt install -y unzip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-tools-5.15.0-53 : Depends: linux-tools-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

```
root@deploy:~# apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-tools-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-tools-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 56 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/314 kB of archives.
After this operation, 732 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 73758 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-tools-common_5.15.0-53.59_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-common (5.15.0-53.59) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_5.15.0-53.59_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/acpidbg', which is also in package linux-intel-iotg-tools-common 5.15.0-1018.23
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_5.15.0-53.59_all.deb
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@deploy:~#
```

```
root@deploy:~# apt update -y
Hit:1 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
60 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.


root@deploy:~# sudo apt-get install -f 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-tools-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-tools-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 60 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/314 kB of archives.
After this operation, 732 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 73758 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-tools-common_5.15.0-53.59_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-common (5.15.0-53.59) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_5.15.0-53.59_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/acpidbg', which is also in package linux-intel-iotg-tools-common 5.15.0-1018.23
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_5.15.0-53.59_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@deploy:~#
```

resolved by https://superuser.com/questions/1291372/what-is-the-step-by-step-procedure-to-fix-the-the-following-packages-have-unmet

```
root@deploy:~# sudo dpkg --force-all -i /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-common_5.15.0-53.59_all.deb
(Reading database ... 73758 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-tools-common_5.15.0-53.59_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-common (5.15.0-53.59) ...
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/acpidbg', which is also in package linux-intel-iotg-tools-common 5.15.0-1018.23
......
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man8/x86_energy_perf_policy.8.gz', which is also in package linux-intel-iotg-tools-common 5.15.0-1018.23
Setting up linux-tools-common (5.15.0-53.59) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
root@deploy:~# 
root@deploy:~# apt install -y unzip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  zip
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  unzip
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 60 not upgraded.
Need to get 174 kB of archives.
After this operation, 385 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 unzip amd64 6.0-26ubuntu3.1 [174 kB]
Fetched 174 kB in 2s (108 kB/s) 
Selecting previously unselected package unzip.
(Reading database ... 73761 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../unzip_6.0-26ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking unzip (6.0-26ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up unzip (6.0-26ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Scanning processes...                                                                                                                                                                    
Scanning processor microcode...                                                                                                                                                          
Scanning linux images...                                                                                                                                                                 

Running kernel seems to be up-to-date.

The processor microcode seems to be up-to-date.

No services need to be restarted.

No containers need to be restarted.

No user sessions are running outdated binaries.

No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host.
root@deploy:~#
```